# winnt.h errors on VS Command Prompt

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, scons

I'm trying to develop an NPAPI plugin using NIXYSA (http://code.google.com/p/nixysa/) which uses Scons for building the project. Now I'm just trying to build the Hello World sample app.
The problem is that, after generating the C source files, it runs into weird winnt.h errors when compiling.
Below is the command it uses and the result:

```
c:\Users\Mo\Documents\Projects\Chrome Plugin\nixysa-read-only\examples\hel
lo_world>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\vc\bin\cl" /Foglue\
globals_glue.obj /c glue\globals_glue.cc /TP /nologo /DWIN32 /DOS_WINDOWS /I. /I
 "C:\Users\Mo\Documents\Projects\Chrome Plugin\nixysa-read-only\nixysa\sta
tic_glue\npapi" /I "C:\Users\Mo\Documents\Projects\Chrome Plugin\nixysa-re
ad-only\third_party\npapi\include" /Iglue
globals_glue.cc
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(6361) : error C2146
: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ContextRecord'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(6361) : error C4430
: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(6361) : error C4430
: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12983) : error C206
5: 'PCONTEXT' : undeclared identifier
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12984) : error C214
6: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ContextRecord'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12984) : warning C4
229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12984) : error C218
2: 'RtlCaptureContext' : illegal use of type 'void'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12984) : error C249
1: 'RtlCaptureContext' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(12984) : error C205
9: syntax error : ')'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(13372) : error C214
3: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(13372) : error C443
0: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(13376) : error C443
0: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\winnt.h(14982) : error C386
1: '__readfsdword': identifier not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(342) : war
ning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Sp
ecify /EHsc
```

I've searched pretty much and the only solution that is suggested is for when the DXSDK headers cause conflict and they should be mentioned later in the list of include directories. I do have DXSDK installed, but the include directories aren't in the list for my VS9, nor in the "vcvars32.txt" of VS 2008 command prompt.

The four lines defining the variables of the VS command prompt are :

```
@set PATH=%DevEnvDir%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\BIN;%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools;%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Tools\bin;%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%;%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%\Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 (Pre-Release Version);%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\VCPackages;%PATH%
@set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\INCLUDE;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\INCLUDE
@set LIB=%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\LIB;%VCINSTALLDIR%\LIB;%LIB%
@set LIBPATH=%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%;%FrameworkDir%\%FrameworkVersion%;%VCINSTALLDIR%\ATLMFC\LIB;%VCINSTALLDIR%\LIB;%LIBPATH%
```

In VS command prompt I get the following for echo %INCLUDE% :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SD
Ks\Windows\v7.0\include;
```

I ran the cl.exe command both in command prompt (using the nixysa script) and in VS command prompt, both gave the same errors.
I don't think there's any problems in the generated C code, since it's the unedited Hello World which is basically tested and others don't seem to be having problem with.

So any ideas? Could the problem be in the winnt.h it is using or ?

More info: Win 7 x64 on Intel Core 2 Duo

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a define for

```
_X86_
```

http://andre-selmanagic.com/blog/2010/08/02/compiling-a-npapi-plugin-from-the-mozilla-source-code/

Comment: Dear **Peter**: the link you've mentioned is not available any more.

Comment: @FaezeAlahabadi I have fixed the url since it was just broken by a website reorganization. Iirc all that is required is to add 

    #define _X86_ 

(for some reason I can not get the underscores to appear)

to your code or to have your build system pass the define to the compiler. The link is just for background and attribution.